# How to extend CodeIgniter cache adapter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, extend

How do I extend CodeIgniter cache adapter? I tried with:

```
MY_Cache_file extends CI_Cache_file{
   ...
}


MY_Cache_apc extends CI_Cache_apc{
   ...
}
```

but doesn't seem to work... Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible. It's still a feature which should be implemented:
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/179